# Every Connected Regular Space With Countable Basis is Uncountable Incorrect Counter-Example

Tags: general-topology

I had to answer the question: Prove or Disprove: Every connected regular space with a countable basis is uncountable. This, of course, is true, however I thought of a "counter-example" and I am not sure why it does not work. Consider the following:

Define space $X := \{\frac{m}{n}:m,n \in \mathbb Z^+, m \leq n\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ under the standard topology. Of course, $X$ is countable and it seems to me that because rationals are dense in the reals, this space is both connected and regular. This cannot be true because it would disprove this theorem. What then, is incorrect with my example? Could someone provide an example of either a separation of this space or a point and a closed set that do not have disjoint neighborhoods containing them? Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is false as $X = \emptyset$ or one-point space shows

Comment: For a separation just consider some irrational between two points of $X$...

Comment: Your space $X$ is disconnected. The set $[0,1/e)\cap \mathbb Q$ is open (by definition of subspace topology), and its complement $(1/e,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ is open as well (same argument).

Comment: Have to be careful about your definitions here - Often "regular" does not assume $T_1$, in which case trivial topology on any set is regular and connected, and has countable base (if "countable" can include finite).

Comment: Spaces satisfying (Connected Λ Regular Λ Second Countable Λ Countable): https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Connected%2BRegular%2BSecond%20Countable%2BCountable

Comment: In particular, having a countable basis isn't necessary here: https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments: your set is disconnected due to the separation $(-1,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}),(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},2)$.

The theorem as stated is false: the countable set $\mathbb Z$ with the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset,\mathbb Z\}$ is regular (in fact, pseudometrizable), connected, and has a countable basis.

The theorem should really be something like [T81 of $\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000081): every connected $T_3$ (regular and, importantly, $T_0$) space with at least two points is uncountable. Having a countable basis isn't necessary, but of course that assumption may make the proof easier if it's allowed.